# Why move where clause to join clause produce different result

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQl server I have two big tables with each one about 500,000,000 records,
I expect that these two query produce same result, but not!

```
select count(*)
from ff
         left join d on
    ff.ID = d.id
where ff.sendtime < '2023-01-21' and d.id is null
```

```
select count(*)
from ff
         left join d on
    ff.sendtime < '2023-01-21' and ff.ID = d.id
where d.id is null
```

Comment: The two queries are different so why are you expecting them to be the same? And `500,000,000,000,000` is quite a lot of rows.

Comment: @Stu  Sorry I Corrected It

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### First query

Select all ff rows before 2023-01-21. Then outer join all d rows on the ID. Then dismiss all rows where ff had a match in dd. Thus you select all ff rows before 2023-01-21 for which not exists a d row.

### Second query

Select all ff rows, no matter which date. Outer join all d rows based on the ID and the ff date. Then dismiss all rows where ff had a match in dd. Thus you select all ff rows the senddate of which is >= 2023-01-21 or that don't have a match in d.

### Anti joins

Anti joins, where you outer join a table and only keep the outer joined rows, are meant to select data where there is no matching data in that table. I consider `NOT EXISTS` or `NOT IN` way more readable than the join. These clauses make plain what you want to select and what the condition is for selecting the data, by putting the table of interest in the `FROM` clause and the lookup of the other table in the `WHERE` clause.

This is how I'd write the first query:

```
select count(*)
from ff
where sendtime < '2023-01-21'
and not exists (select * from d where d.id = ff.id);
```

This is how I'd write the second query:

```
select count(*)
from ff
where sendtime >= '2023-01-21'
or not exists (select * from d where d.id = ff.id);
```

Comment: Which one has better performance? not exists  or left join

Comment: Select even 1 row in first query takes too long

Comment: @SnowStorm As a rule, the `not exists` can usually be transformed into a merge/heap join anyway, and the `left join` tends to mess up cardinality/unique constraints on the data therefore causing other issues further down the plan. So normally better to just use `not exists`

Answer (score 0):

In the first query the left join between tables ff and d is performed based on the "ID" column where as in the second it checks "ff.sendtime" is less than given time i.e.., 2023-01-21 and "ID" is matching in two tables or not.

Comment: How does this differ from the OP's first query?

Comment: If you want to have the same result you could execute the same query ;)